# Animation of clicking a button and a hover handler in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, button, ontouchlistener

I need to implement an animation as in the picture below. How can I achieve this same effect in an Android app? When we press a button, one letter stands out -we start to move our finger, and with the same animation others stand out. As soon as we release the finger, all buttons return to their original state.

[image]

I tried to implement this by creating several `TextViews`, and in the selector I set a color change, but this does not result in the desired animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/playground_rounded_selected_button"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/playground_rounded_selected_button"
    android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/playground_rounded_button" />
</selector>
```

How can I track `onHover` movements if some button has already been pressed to add all the pressed buttons in an `ArrayList` in code? Any help or hint to the solution of the problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Hover isn't a concept in Android.  Anything you do with this will need to be custom coded in touch handlers by you.

Comment: Ok, but how to use them in my task?

Comment: you need to make different image for that.

Comment: I am already using two different drawable files in the background of textview, but how to implement the same animation  given in the picture?